# perform a select statement on two or three partition at the same time

Tags: oracle

I have a set of partitions from 1 to 20.
I have this Query below

```
select * from table1 partition (1);
```

I would like to do the same statement but on two or three partitions at the same time but not the whole table.
What would be the correct query to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select * from table1 partition (1)
UNION ALL
select * from table1 partition (2)
UNION ALL
select * from table1 partition (3)
--etc.
;
```